# I found some newly posted questions with duplicate titles. Is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-review, questions, title

I just saw at least two new posts with a title that matches two existing canonical duplicates:

- [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74788714/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) (duplicating [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it))
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74788833/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it (duplicating [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it))

As far as I'm aware, posting duplicate titles should not be possible and should produce an error that the title already exists. How was it possible that these two new questions were posted?

---

<sup>The fact they match the canonical exactly demonstrates why this was not allowed in the first place</sup>

Comment: Presumably related to the staging ground?

Comment: Neither post came through the Staging Ground. (That doesn't necessarily mean that some piece of validation hasn't gone missing due to the beta launch, but this is not a direct case of posts going through the Staging Ground circumventing the title check)

Comment: There seem to be [quite some questions with duplicate titles](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1688021/find-duplicate-question-titles) (the empty titles are probably proposed articles) - Are you sure this is a hard restriction?

Comment: @dan1st I'm not sure when it was introduced, but writing a title which already existed would add a red border around the title, and disallow you from posting (and I believe it might show a link to the existing question with that title). That said, I don't regularly ask questions, and I previously only noticed it when editing questions, when trying to clean up/improve titles (and because of metaposts with people complaining about this check).

Comment: What I find extra strange is that I can't really imagine anyone would actually use the title "What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?" exactly phrased like that. It seems a very deliberate choice to use the exact title of the canonical down to the use of punctuation.

Comment: @Gimby might be an artefact of the suggestion system. It says something like "Did you mean <list of questions>" which the user might have taken as a prompt to re-write the title to one of these.

Comment: Strange. There's nothing in common between the two users, nor anything indicating they're the same person.  I would've blamed the wizard, but only one of the two users went through the wizard

Comment: @VLAZ that sounds very human, indeed.

Comment: I saw this as well: [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74767319), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74752755) (10K links from my flag history). Asked [in Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62563004#62563004) if there can be a way to tune SD to catch issues like this

Comment: @dan1st: At the least, it looks like this restriction was [originally implemented in September 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106796/335251). According to [this Q&A on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118953/335251), the check doesn't apply to deleted questions with the same title, but it does apply to closed questions with the same title (though it was changed in January 2012 so that moderators can reuse the title of an existing closed question).

Comment: ...And [this Q&A on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265749/335251) indicates that the duplicate-title restriction is case-sensitive. It seems like the duplicate-title restriction only looks for completely identical titles (including spacing), judging from all of those Q&As together. (...Anyway, this issue has now been forwarded to the devs to look into.)

Comment: @V2Blast Brand new example, matches case and everything... old question ~ [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/178325/283366), new question [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74819386/283366)

Comment: @Phil Thanks, the examples I listed also match exactly, so something fishy is going on or the restriction has been removed.